# if statement syntax equal to

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, strpos

I am using Views php in Drupal 6. I need to do an if statement to find if nodehierarchy_parent is equal to the value 0. Then do something. Right now I have it set to if the value contains a 0. My code is below.

```
    <?php
       if (strpos($data->nodehierarchy_parent,'0')) {
       print 'hello';
    }
       else print $data->nodehierarchy_parent;
    ?>
```

Comment: Um `if ($data->nodehierarchy_parent == 0) {`

Comment: This works John. I want to accept your answer as correct but can't do it for a reply

Answer (score 1):

I am new to stack. John's comment solved my problem but I cant mark his comment as correct answer. Below is the final code that worked.

```
   <?php
      if ($data->nodehierarchy_parent == 0) {
      print 'hello';
   }
      else print $data->nodehierarchy_parent;
   ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo (strpos($data->nodehierarchy_parent,'0') === false)
    ? $data->nodehierarchy_parent 
    : 'hello';
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation? Code-only answers are not as friendly since they may not be obvious to others.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posed. -1.